# A recurrence equation problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've been stuck with this problem:

With the help of recurrence equations, solve the following: There is a chart with dimensions $1 \times n$. We have dominos in two different colors which we should use to fill up the chart. In how many different ways can the chart be filled?

I'm hopeless with recurrence problems. I hope someone can explain how this particular problem should be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to use recurrence relations, note that a chart of length $n$ can be filled by filling the first $n-2$ squares then placing one more domino at the end.

You can do it without recurrence by noting that you have $\frac n2$ places to put dominoes and $2$ choices at each place.